# Finding centroids in a large image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scipy

I am working with large 3D images (about 8000x5000x50) that contain about 1000 to 10000 labeled segmentations, i.e. connected regions of integers. I need to find the center of mass for each object, but what I've tried is much too slow. Using scipy's `center_of_mass()` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass.html), I just looped over all labels like this:

```
coords = []
for label in range(1, n):
    print("label " + str(label))
    coord = ndimage.center_of_mass(labels, labels, label)
    coords.append(coord)
```

This works fine but it takes easily five seconds per label. What could be a faster way?

Comment: thats around 8Gb of an image. It will be slow.

Comment: Doing it in parallel, e.g. using threads, may make it 2-8x faster on a typical multi-core machine.

Comment: Can't you calculate the centroid in a downsampled version of the image and scale it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Good idea, but since I can't parallelize the existing algorithm, I'd need to cut up the image which would also destroy some of the objects. dhanuska I don't think so, since most objects are maybe 10 to 20 pixels in diameter--some even less and they might get lost, or at least the centroid will become quite imprecise. I tried extracting the bounding box of each object and calculate the centroid from that--this takes around one second for 1000 objects! But I somehow need to transform the coordinates back into the whole image.. Ander Biguri, I always trust in Python/numpy magic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to speed things up by getting the bounding boxes of each labeled object from the large source image (called `labels`), calling `center_of_mass()` on each of them individually and translating the result back into the coordinate space of the source image:

```
coords = []
# Get bounding boxes for all objects in the form of slices
objects = ndimage.find_objects(labels)
# Loop over all objects:
for l in range(1, n):
    # Get individual bounding box
    bb_slices = objects[l]
    # Extract object
    obj = labels[bb_slices]
    # Compute centroid
    coord = ndimage.center_of_mass(obj)
    # Translate result from coordinate space of the bounding box back to the source image by simply adding the starting coordinate of each slice
    coord_translated = (np.around(coord[0]).astype(np.uint8) + slices[0].start,       np.around(coord[1]).astype(np.uint8) +
                    slices[1].start, np.around(coord[2]).astype(np.uint8) + slices[2].start)
    coords.append(coord_translated)
```

This takes only about 16 seconds for >900 objects, compared to at least an hour for the original method.